# ispconfig3.1 cannot issue letsencrypt certificate

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt, ispconfig

For some reason, I can no longer issue letsencrypt certificate from the console. It used to work...

The Apache error log shows:
[ssl:warn] [pid 2397] AH01906: xxx.xxx.xxx:8080:0 server certificate is a CA certificate
[ssl:error] [pid 2397] AH02217: ssl_stapling_init_cert: can't retrieve issuer certificate!
[ssl:error] [pid 2397] AH02604: Unable to configure certificate xxx.xxx.xxx

The domain name (xxx.xxx.xxx) is the server's name not the website name I want to issue the cert to

Port 8080 was never opened to the world.